# PHPMailer sending Calendar event to outlook mail

Tags: php, email, outlook, calendar, phpmailer

I know there are many questions related to PHPMailer, I tried most of them but no luck still,

I need to send Calendar event to gmail & outlook, which i have achieved for Gmail with below script But for outlook the ics file has send as attachment not as a calendar event.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com"; 
$mail->Username = SMTP_EMAIL; // defined as constant
$mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD; // defined as constant
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->isHTML(FALSE);
$mail->setFrom('k***@gmail.com', 'name');
$mail->addReplyTo('k***@gmail.com', 'name');

$mail->addAddress('v***@gmail.com', 'Gmail'); // to gmail
$mail->addAddress('k***@outlook.com','Outlook'); // to outlook
$mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar';

$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "PRODID:-//LothCalendar//ATMRequest//EN\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=\"MAILTO:k***@gmail.com\":MAILTO:ke***@outlook.com\r\n";
$ical .= "UID:".strtoupper(md5($event_id))."-lothcalendar.local\r\n";
// $ical .= "ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=k***@outlook.com;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:k***@gmail.com\r\n";
$ical .= "ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Namekeviveks:mailto:k***@gmail.com\r\n";
$ical .= "SEQUENCE:".$sequence."\r\n";
$ical .= "STATUS:".$status."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTAMPTZID=Asia/Calcutta:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$start."T".$start_time."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND:".$end."T".$end_time."\r\n";
$ical .= "LOCATION:".$venue."\r\n";
$ical .= "SUMMARY:".$summary."\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:some sample event description\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

$mail->Subject = "Invitation: Outlook Calendar Event";
$mail->AddStringAttachment($ical, "event.ics", "7bit", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");

$mail->Body = "Test Outlook Calendar event mail";
$mail->Ical = $ical;
//send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->send()) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
```

I have already tried with

**1. Custom Headers**

```
    $mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-version',"1.0"); 
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type',"text/calendar; name=event.ics; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8;"); 
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type',"text/html; charset=UTF-8"); 
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding',"7bit"); 
    $mail->addCustomHeader('X-Mailer',"Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0"); 
    $mail->addCustomHeader("Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
```

not worked in both Gmail and Outlook (mail send as normal text of ICS content)

**2. EasyPeasyICS**

```
    $invite = new EasyPeasyICS();
    $invite->addEvent('06-06-2016 08:00:00','06-06-2016 17:00:00',"TEST","TEST","");
    $mail->Ical = $invite->render(false);
```

not worked in both Gmail and Outlook (mail send as normal text of ICS content)

**3. AddStringAttachment**

```
    $mail->AddStringAttachment($ical, "event.ics", "7bit", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");
```

works in gmail but sending event.ics as attachment in outlook

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Gmail handles calendars incorrectly - it's simply broken.

If you want them to work in both Gmail and Outlook you need to add the calendar item both as a `text/calendar` part within a `multipart/alternative` message **and** as an attachment. This is very stupid, but it's what happens when email client developers don't read standards, which is pretty much business as usual for gmail as it's broken in many other ways too.

You can't fudge this by adding random headers; the ones you've tried are likely to break things quite badly.

There is [an open ticket for this in PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175) with more detail, but it's unlikely to be resolved any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I get this to work in Gmail, Office 365, MS Outlook, Zoho mail and iPhone Mail App was by creating and appointment in MS Outlook, download the archive, open it with a text editor like VS Code and paste it in the StringAttachment, without easypeasyics, something like this:

```
$ical_content = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:SA Pacific Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20191203T124654Z
DESCRIPTION:Cumbre LATAM 2019\n
DTEND;TZID="SA Pacific Standard Time":20191210T220000
DTSTAMP:20191203T124654Z
DTSTART;TZID="SA Pacific Standard Time":20191210T150000
LAST-MODIFIED:20191203T124654Z
LOCATION:The Westin Lima Hotel & Convention Center
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=es:Event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A06260CDADA9D501000000000000000
    010000000FC95C5664F74B04B8AEB1601B7F04AD6
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-mic
    rosoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/


<!---- THERE IS A BUNCH OF CODE THAT OUTLOOK GENERATE HERE BUT IT OVERFLOWS THE ANSWER CAPACITY, BUT WITHOUT IT, THE APPOINTMENT DOESN'T WORK ----->


X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';


    $mail = new PHPMailer;      
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '';  // Specicfy main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@appointment.pe', '');      
    $mail->addAddress($data['email'], $data['name']);       
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@appointment.pe', '');           
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $data['subject'];
    $mail->MsgHTML($data['body']); 
    $mail->addStringAttachment($ical_content,'ical.ics','base64','text/calendar');
```